# Awaitmessage and ToLowerCase() not working together

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So in my code, I'm trying to make messages be accepted if they're any case. Eg true = TRuE . However when doing this I'm getting a result I'm not expecting.

Instead of giving me an error, or doing what I expect. It goes strait to sending a message saying "Time Up".

```
const safari = function (message) {
            message.channel.send(embed).then(() => {
                message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
                    .then(collected => {
                        if (collected.first().toLowerCase() == "look at reflection") {
                            const embed2 = new discord.RichEmbed()
                                .setTitle("__**Chat to a tourist!**__")
                                .setColor("#49499c")
                                .setDescription("You begin to look at yourself, and slowly become infatuated with yourself!\n**__Wait 24 hours before guessing again!__**")
                            message.channel.send(embed2);
                        }
                        else if (collected.first() == "Pond dip") {
                            const embed2 = new discord.RichEmbed()
                                .setTitle("__**Off road!**__")
                                .setColor("#49499c")
                                .setDescription("You begin to pond dip, you had such a blast!")
                            message.channel.send(embed2);
                        }
                        else if (collected.first() == "Chase a frog") {
                            const embed2 = new discord.RichEmbed()
                                .setTitle("__**Trip over a rock!**__")
                                .setColor("#49499c")
                                .setDescription("Oh you're very clumbsy luckily its only a bruise!")
                            message.channel.send(embed2);
                        }
                        else { message.channel.send("Could not find this answer"); return safari(message); }
                    })
                    .catch(collected => { message.channel.send('Time up'); });
            });
```

If anyone could explain to me why this is happening, and a possible way to a solution I would be so greatful!

Comment: You are not using toLowerCase anywhere on your code, only toUpperCase and against a lowercase string.

Comment: Sorry, had changed that during testing, it should've been toLowerCase. The problem still remains though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem here. You can't use `collected.first().toLowerCase()`. You have to use `collected.first().content.toLowerCase()` because `collected.first()` is a Message object.

Also, is the filter variable defined?

Comment: Thanks this worked! and yes it was defined. it was just this.
```const filter = response => {
            return response.author.id === message.author.id;
            }       ```

Comment: Also, just to help my understanding, does `.content` just take the string value of it?

Answer (score 0):

It's really using a variable for toLowerCase() result and use logic with a switch or ifs with lowercase values for a correct comparison.

```
const safari = function(message) {
    message.channel.send(embed).then(()=>{
        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
            max: 1,
            time: 30000,
            errors: ['time']
        }).then(collected=>{
            let msg = collected.first().toLowerCase();

            /* switch version */
            switch (msg) {
            case "look at reflection":
                {
                    const embed2 = new discord.RichEmbed().setTitle("__**Chat to a tourist!**__").setColor("#49499c").setDescription("You begin to look at yourself, and slowly become infatuated with yourself!\n**__Wait 24 hours before guessing again!__**")
                    message.channel.send(embed2);
                    break;
                }
            case "pond dip":
                {
                    const embed2 = new discord.RichEmbed().setTitle("__**Off road!**__").setColor("#49499c").setDescription("You begin to pond dip, you had such a blast!")
                    message.channel.send(embed2);
                    break;
                }
            case "chase a frog":
                {
                    const embed2 = new discord.RichEmbed().setTitle("__**Trip over a rock!**__").setColor("#49499c").setDescription("Oh you're very clumbsy luckily its only a bruise!")
                    message.channel.send(embed2);
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    message.channel.send("Could not find this answer");
                    return safari(message);
                }
            }

            /* if version */

            if (msg == "look at reflection") {
                const embed2 = new discord.RichEmbed().setTitle("__**Chat to a tourist!**__").setColor("#49499c").setDescription("You begin to look at yourself, and slowly become infatuated with yourself!\n**__Wait 24 hours before guessing again!__**")
                message.channel.send(embed2);
            } else if (msg == "pond dip") {
                const embed2 = new discord.RichEmbed().setTitle("__**Off road!**__").setColor("#49499c").setDescription("You begin to pond dip, you had such a blast!")
                message.channel.send(embed2);
            } else if (msg == "chase a frog") {
                const embed2 = new discord.RichEmbed().setTitle("__**Trip over a rock!**__").setColor("#49499c").setDescription("Oh you're very clumbsy luckily its only a bruise!")
                message.channel.send(embed2);
            } else {
                message.channel.send("Could not find this answer");
                return safari(message);
            }
        }
        ).catch(collected=>{
            message.channel.send('Time up');
        }
        );
    }
    );
}
```

Maybe you can upgrade your JS with ES6 and async/await instead of Promises style
Also.. if use answers storaged it can be more flexible
try some like this...

```js
class Message extends String {
    channel = new Channel()
}
class Channel {
    async awaitMessages(filter, options) {
        let messages = new Collection();
        messages.push(new Message("pond dip"))
        return messages;
    }
    async send(msg) {

    }
}

class Collection extends Array {
    first() {
        return this[0];
    }
}
class Discord {
    RichEmbed() {
        return new Element()
    }
}
class Element {
    setTitle() {
        return this;
    }
    setColor() {
        return this;
    }
    setDescription() {
        return this;
    }
}

let discord = new Discord()
let answers =
{
    "look at reflection": { title: "__**Chat to a tourist!**__", color: "#49499c", description: "You begin to look at yourself, and slowly become infatuated with yourself!\n**__Wait 24 hours before guessing again!__**" },
    "pond dip": { title: "__**Off road!**__", color: "#49499c", description: "You begin to pond dip, you had such a blast!" },
    "chase a frog": { title: "__**Trip over a rock!**__", color: "#49499c", description: "Oh you're very clumbsy luckily its only a bruise!" },
}

async function safari(message) {
    try {


        let embed = "embed";
        let filter = undefined;
        await message.channel.send(embed);
        let collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
            max: 1,
            time: 30000,
            errors: ['time']
        });
        let msg = collected.first().toLowerCase();

        let answer = answers[msg];
        if (answer) {
            const embed2 = discord.RichEmbed().setTitle(answer.title).setColor(answer.color).setDescription(answer.description)
            return message.channel.send(embed2);
        } else {
            return message.channel.send("Could not find this answer");
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return message.channel.send('Time up');
    }
}
safari(new Message("test"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the same problem still occurs. Thanks for pointing out how my code changed though. I always forget about switches.